# Analyse SWF-Files with Java

Tags: java, flash

I stumbled upon the need to find out (inside Java code) which files are dynamically loaded by an SWF-file. Is there any possibility to get a list of paths of every object referenced inside?
I tried out some libraries without proper documentation and gave up. Although I ran out of Google Search Phrases... ;)
Maybe there is an external tool which can be accessed by Java via command line?

Ggreat thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to inspect the _compiled_ SWF file, right?

Comment: Yes, it's for automated website analysing, getting information about every file used inside a page. These files behind flash are the last missing part. The rest is done by some nasty XSLT2-code...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get to the information you need using the **dump** tool which is part of [Apparat](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/).

I use actionscript more than Java, so I also recommend having a look at [AS3SWF](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) which is a great library you could use to load and analyze the swf you need. Think of it as decompiling at runtime.

Either way, the [SWF Format Specifications](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) will come in handy.

I'm not sure there's something that does exactly what you want, but I imagine you could collect all the strings (DefineText tags), loop through them and run an URL RegEx against them.

Answer (score 0):

I think even if you could analyze a SWF file, you can't be sure to get this information. I have Flex Project (finally a swf file) which dynamically loads some modules, but the names (URLs) of the available modules are requested from the server. So there is no chance to retrieve this information from the main swf file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in my case only some xml-files, images and movies are loaded (as far as I see it in Firebug). Right now I "know" where to load these files, but any changes should be detected automatically. Seems like Google has some method to index files behind a flash application... ;)

Comment: @Kai AFAIK Google has a partnership with Adobe and they have a bespoke version of Flash Player that can easily crawl swf files. This would help SEO for SWF files.